# Why do we call word embeddings "vectors" ? Shouldn't we call them word coordinates?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, word-embeddings, latent-semantic-analysis

Word embeddings are often referred to as vectors. For instance, "Word embedding models are dense vector representations of words learned from a corpus of natural language" (Rosado, 2020). Would it be more precise to talk about word coordinates, or word scalars ?

My rough understanding of embeddings is that they are representations of where the word resides in a conceptual space: a sparse coocurence matrix is transformed using a dimension reduction technique, transposing each word into a *k*-dimension Euclidean space.

Based on that assumption, the "vector" associated with each word would therefore be a set of coordinates. A list of embeddings would therefore be the list of coordinates where the elements reside in the *k* dimension space. The elements are geometrical points in that space, having no volume, no direction and no magnitude, they would be *scalars*.

It is possible that I am indeed confused, and that embeddings really *are* geometrical vectors, and would like to read an explanation if that is the case.

An alternate explanation is that we are talking about vectors in a computational sense (a list of numbers), not a geometrical sense. In that case, I believe that making that clarification would help.

---

Rozado, D. (2020). Wide range screening of algorithmic bias in word embedding models using large sentiment lexicons reveals underreported bias types. PloS one, 15(4), e0231189.

Comment: we call them vectors because they are treated like elements of a linear space: we add them, subtract them, multiply them by constants, and compute projections of them.

Comment: Also, the direction of a vector is the direction from the point (0,0,...,0) to the coordinates of that vector.